# Python writes only last line in the new csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have only last line written in a new csv file.

```
f = open(r'dataset.csv', encoding="utf8")
data = f.readlines()

tagged_list = []

for line in data:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    adj = [word for word,pos in tagged \
            if (pos == 'JJ' or pos == 'JJR' or pos == 'JJS')]
    downcased = [x.lower() for x in adj]
    joined = " ".join(downcased).encode('utf-8')
    into_string = str(adj)

output = open("out.csv", "wb")
output.write(joined)
output.close()
```

When I change  `output = open("out.csv", "a")` or `output = open("out.csv", "r")` I m getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nl.py", line 21, in <module>
    output.write(joined)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

How can I make it write all the lines one after another and not only the last line.

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `joined` in each iteration of the loop. `joined += ...` would be the quickest fix.

Comment: `joined += " ".join(downcased).encode('utf-8')` 
returns me the following error:
 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nltkadj.py", line 18, in <module>
    joined += " ".join(downcased).encode('utf-8')
NameError: name 'joined' is not defined `

Comment: Initialize it before the loops begins. (Or, just open `out.csv` before the loop and write to it as you compute each line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open both files, and write the lines as you generate them (untested):

```
with open('dataset.csv', encoding='utf8') as data:
    with open('out.csv','w',encoding='utf8') as output:
        for line in data:
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
            adj = [word for word,pos in tagged
                   if (pos == 'JJ' or pos == 'JJR' or pos == 'JJS')]
            downcased = [x.lower() for x in adj]
            joined = " ".join(downcased) + '\n'
            output.write(joined)
```